# Table with user emails who haven't signed up?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Not sure if this question has been answered elsewhere; I searched but I couldn't find a similar question.

I have a database table (tb_users) with a list of users, ID is primary, EMAIL is unique

I have another database table (tb_memberships) with a list of memberships that refer to tb_users by ID.

I'd like the memberships be added and revoked based on email addresses, not based on their IDs so that a user who HASN'T signed up yet be granted the membership when they sign up. How should I design the table so that a user (that hasn't signed up yet) can be added to the memberships table. Is it a good idea to make the foreign key in tb_memberships the users' email address? Or should these 'pending' memberships have their own table?

Comment: Almost always better to use an ID than a string. ID is also unique. I don't understand why their ID wouldn't work in your case?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton If the user hasn't signed up yet, I don't have a record in the tb_users table to refer to.

Comment: Right, but that means you don't have their email either - right?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Not correct, the membership enrolments are created by an admin for everyone who is eligible for the membership regardless of whether they signed up or not. If they haven't signed up yet, I have their email address, but I don't have a record in tb_users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a "ghost_account" boolean to the users table. Using a scope in Rails, I ignored all users who are considered "ghosts" so they can't log in and can sign up normally (ghost_account boolean is set to false once the user signs up). That way, I have a user ID that can be linked to everything else, even if the user hasn't signed up yet.